# jquery .change(function) cant call class function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a validation script in JavaScript with jQuery and am using the .change() function from jQuery, when the input value is changed I want it to call an object function from itself, displayError(). The function is called from child classes when they are constructed.

The class:

```js
class Input { //this makes a class that all inputs should be assigned to
  constructor(input, error) {
    this.inputBox = input; //jQuery Object of the input box
    this.errorText = error; //jQuery Object of the error text
    this.required = this.inputBox.prop("required"); //return true if the inputBox has attribute required and false if not
    this.unique = this.inputBox.prop("data-unique"); //USED FOR KNOWING IF NEEDED TO QUERY IN DATABASE
    this.errorText.hide(); //hides the error text
  }

  displayError() { //function that will decide whether the error text needs displaying
    var valid = this.auth(); //sees if the value of the input box is valid
    //QUERY DB TO SEE IF TAKEN
    if (!valid) {
      this.errorText.show(); //shows the error text
    }
    //else if TAKEN && this.unique{SHOW DIFFERENT MESSAGE}
    else { //runs if the value is valid
      this.errorText.hide(); //hides the error text
    }
  }

  auth() {
    let value = this.inputBox.val(); //asssigns the value of the input box to 'value'
    if ((!this.required && value == "") || this.isValid(value)) { //if not required the value can be nothing, but if it is required then the value must be validated
      return true; //says the value is valid
    } else {
      return false;
    } //says the value is not valid
  }

  liveErrors() {
    this.inputBox.change(function() {
      this.displayError()
    }); // <--- ISSUE HERE
  }
}
```

All of my class variables are set and are working, I'm not sure if it is because after the .change() I am referencing this in a function which is not set because it is not global variable, if that is the issue I am not sure how to overcome that.

I am very new to JavaScript and OOP, sorry if i have any incorrect terminology or have done something stupid, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the anonymous inner function used as the callback for `this.inputBox.change`, `this` is the element `this.inputBox` is pointing to, which is the input element in the dom. You can verify that with a call to `console.log( this, typeof this );` in that function before trying to call `this.displayError();`

You can use [jQuery.proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to call your member function with your chosen context, `this`.

I stripped down your code and used keypress instead of change for the example snippet, but you can see that it will work to trigger instance methods by typing in the two input fields and seeing that they triggering changes to their instance specific member elements.

Inside of your member function, `this` should work just as expected.

```js
class Input { //this makes a class that all inputs should be assigned to

  constructor(input, error) {
    this.inputBox = input; //jQuery Object of the input box
    this.errorText = error; //jQuery Object of the error text
  }

  toggleError() { //function that will decide whether the error text needs displaying
    this.errorText.toggle(); //hides the error text
  }

  liveErrors() {
    this.inputBox.keypress($.proxy(this, 'toggleError'));
  }
}

let first = new Input($('.first-input'), $('.first-error'));
let second = new Input($('.second-input'), $('.second-error'));

first.liveErrors();
second.liveErrors();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="first-input">
<span class="first-error">First!</span>
<br/>
<input class="second-input">
<span class="second-error">Second!</span>
```